# Do these two r.v. generate the same $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, and the r.v.  $X,Y:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

If we define $X(\omega)=\omega$ and $Y(\omega)=1-\omega$. The book I'm reading, simply states that these two r.v. will generate the same sigma algebras, but how could I prove it?

$X^{-1}(B)=B\cap[0,1]$, for any $B \subset \mathbb{R}$. I was trying to write $Y^{-1}(B)$ in a similar way, but I can only write $Y^{-1}(B)=B^c\cap [0,1]$ if B has no single isolated elements...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this approach: $Y(\omega) = f(X(\omega))$, where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Giovanni thanks ;)

Comment: @Giovanni, sorry again, I thought I understood your approach, but I'm not sure...
you're saying to look at $Y^{-1}(w)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(w))$?

Shouldn't I add that f is bijective, from Borel sigma-algebra to Borel sigma-algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Borelsets are closed under translations and reflections. So For $B\subseteq\mathbb R$:
$$B\text{ is a Borelset if and only if }1-B:=\{1-r\mid r\in B\}\text{ is a Borelset}$$

Note that $Y^{-1}(B)=1-X^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: In both cases I get the Borel sigma algebra intersected with [0,1], right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.